# Declare a matrix symbol

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

How do I declare a matrix symbol of a certain size instead of specifying the every element of the matrix as a symbol and creating the matrix afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MatrixSymbol:

```
>>> A = MatrixSymbol('A', 3, 4)
>>> A[1,1]
A[1, 1]
```